# Java poll on network connections

Tags: java, polling, serversocket

I am writing a program in Java where I have opened 256 network connections on one thread. Whenever there is any data on a socket, I should read it and process the same. Currently, I am using the following approach :

```
while true
do
   iterate over all network connections
   do
         if non-blocking read on socket says there is data
         then
               read data
               process it
         endif
   done
   sleep for 10 milli-seconds
done
```

Is there a better way to do the same on Java ?? I know there is a poll method in C/C++. But after googling for it, I did not get concrete idea about Java's polling. Can somebody explain this ??

Comment: Just a thought...Is 256 network connections for one process not a bit excessive?

Comment: You could create one blocking read thread for each network connection. This way you won't iterate over the connections (it is done by the OS I think) and the thread will wake up when data arrives (no more need for sleep).

Comment: @Quirliom It is needed by the program. I cannot reduce the number of connections.

Comment: @Burkhard This will complicate the programming model. I do not want to invest so much time on this thing when blocking + polling primitives are already provided by the Linux kernel.

Comment: How does a thread wake up? Does connection automatically wake it? Or do we need something else?

Comment: 256 network connections a bit excesive? There are examples of servers that handle x100 x10000 that ammounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [java.nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) package sounds right for what you want to do. It provides ways to perform asynchronous IO.

Comment: It also provides ways to perform *non-blocking* and *multiplexed* I/O, which sound more like what he wants to do.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to http://netty.io/ (this is a non-blocking framework to build network application on java).  https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NettyExampleOfPingPongUsingObject - 'hello world' on netty.