# Java equivalent of C's poll()?

Tags: java, c, polling, file-descriptor

As the title suggests, I'd like to know what is Java's equivalent (or most similar) function to C's `poll()` function for polling a set of file descriptors?

Comment: Package `java.nio`

Comment: Will get something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493272/java-poll-on-network-connections

Comment: I am really interested what will be the exact function in java which will do exactly as C poll.

Comment: What makes you think there is one? There is java.nio.channels.Selector, but nobody said it was exactly the same as poll().

Comment: @EJP I'm just wondering is there, hence the "(or most similar)". Thanks, java.nio.channels.Selector looks like what I need.

Comment: The Selector only works with network sockets and pipes, but the question is about files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @EJP has commented above for **java.nio.channels.Selector**

A **Selector** supports key-based, non-blocking, multiplexed I/O. In other words, selectors
enable you to perform I/O through multiple channels. Selectors are most applicable to socket-backed channels.

It is better to take a look at javadoc for **java.nio.channels.Selector**.

[java.nio.channels.Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html)

This is available since Java <strike>( 7 )</strike> **1.4** and later

Comment: The docu says Since: 1.4 – I guess its only NIO and not NIO.2

Comment: The Selector only works with network sockets and pipes, but the question is about files.